# How to insert Rich text box data using ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, jinja2, richtextbox

I've been trying to insert data into a database using a rich text field in Django using [Django Rich text field](https://github.com/jaap3/django-richtextfield)
as it stands I've been able to have the field working on my form no problem but when I try and link it to my model using ModelFrom with all the other columns I have no luck. 
This form is on a panel completely separate from the admin panel in which it works perfectly fine.

My model is set up to accept the form.

```
class Vulnerability(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
CVSS = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True)
summary = RichTextField(blank=True)
remediation = RichTextField(blank=True)
impact = RichTextField(blank=True)
References = RichTextField(blank=True)
CVE = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Software = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
method = RichTextField(blank=True)
Tags = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
```

my forms.py is set up for that field to use the correct widget (this could be where the issue lies)
I'm not entirely sure how to set up the rich text field in this fashion and I cannot find it in the documentation.

```
class vulnform(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Vulnerability
    fields = ['Tags', 'CVSS', 'CVE', 'Software', 'title','summary']
    widgets = {
        'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'CVE': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'Software': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'Tags': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'CVSS': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','max':10,'min':0}),
        'summary' : RichTextWidget()

    }
```

my views. py looks like this :

class Dashboard(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'vuln_pages/Create_Vuln.html'

```
def get(self, request):
    Outform = {
                # 'Remediation': Remediation,
                 #'References': References,
                 #'Impact': impactform,
                 'vulnform': vulnform,

                 }
    return render(request, self.template_name, Outform)
```

when being displayed the other fields in the from render correctly. i'm rendering them in my template like so:

```
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ vulnform.CVE }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and am trying to render the rich text box like so

```
                                {{ vulnform.summary }}
```

I have had them working before but when the data is in a separate class from all the other columns in the formform.py and I was afraid that when I tried to .save them from a post request they would be saved in different rows in the database.

When I put the input box in my template HTML it renders a text box in the HTML but doesn't seem to load any JS for the rich text box.

```
<textarea name="summary" cols="40" rows="10" class="djrichtextfield" id="id_summary"></textarea>
```

I have tried linking the javascript to the page manually but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching my addon to :
[django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)
everything worked fine.
it seems to have been an issue with the addon.

Comment: That one provides file/image uploading, too, if you set it up right.

Answer (score 1):

Often you need something like `{{ vulnform.media }}` at the top of your form template.  That's where it inserts the needed CSS and JS to properly render forms.  I tried looking at that particular repo, but surprisingly it doesn't explain that.

[Django docs mention how form/widget media is added to a form and then how to add it to the template.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/media/#media-on-forms)

Comment: Even when i load the media it only loads to the page as a textarea box not a richtextbox. it  does seem to load the scripts and the media seems to load fine but still no rich text box.

Comment: I have tried loading the summary field using {{vulnform.summary.as_p}} but when i do this i doesn't even load the inputbox.

Comment: The project says it works with at least 2 different rich text editors, so maybe you have to specify which one before it works?

Comment: yeah, you do that in the settings.py. i've dont that. it's working now after i switched to a different addon for rich text boxes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
in template add 
<div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ vulnform.CVE }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                {{ vulnform.summary }}
                                {{ vulnform.media }} #Here
```